# Как можно изменить параметр в css коде при вводе с клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Например, мне надо изменить ширину этого элемента, в зависимости от введённых данных.

```
#train {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

И желательно ещё, чтобы ввод был через вот такую строку:

```
<input type='number' id='number1' />
```

Comment: А куда данные будут вводится? В Input или просто?

Comment: А при вставке с помощью мыши не нужно менять?

Comment: Вешаете слушатель на `input`, и меняете нужные css свойства элемента при помощи `element.style.cssPropName`, например `document.body.style.color = "black"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
number.addEventListener('input', (ev) => {
  train.style.width = `${ev.target.value}px`;
});
```

```css
#train {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ba8dff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Регулировка ширины линии</h3>
<input type='number' id='number' value="50">px


<div id="train"></div>
```

Либо

```css
#train {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ba8dff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Регулировка ширины линии</h3>
<input type='number' id='number' value="50" oninput="train.style.width = `${this.value}px`;">px


<div id="train"></div>
```

Comment: интересно (+), думаю, будет полезно использовать и в SVG, в частности в различных прогресс барах